# dynamically changing <div> content after click on the link JSF 2

Tags: jsf

My site have a few modules. Header, top-navi, content, footer. I'm including these modules () from other xhtml files. Now i want click some link in top-navi and the included file in content will changed.

How can i do this? I tried in ui:include src=#{bean.method}, which return path of the file which i want, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you elaborate "doesn't work" more in technical developer's terms instead of in ignorant enduser's terms. What *exactly* happens (not)? It should namely work just fine, provided that you preinitialize the property in a proper manner for use during view build time. An [SSCCE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) would help a lot in getting insight into your concrete problem.